# InvalidOperationExceptionSystem in ZombieCheck during delete transaction

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to clear logs from Azure database, and this is the exception I'm getting which seems to only be happening inside of the Azure environment.

```
InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.
  Module "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction", line 16, col 0, in ZombieCheck
    Void ZombieCheck()
  Module "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction", line 53, col 0, in Rollback
    Void Rollback()
  File "D:\BuildAgent5\work\148e47915efc80eb\Janitor.cs", line 108, col 29, in ExecuteDatabaseTransaction
    Void ExecuteDatabaseTransaction(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration, System.String)
  File "D:\BuildAgent5\work\148e47915efc80eb\Startup.cs", line 37, col 17, in .ctor
    Void .ctor()
```

Getting this error after this code is executed:

```
ExecuteDatabaseTransaction(configuration,
     "DELETE profiling.MiniProfilerTimings "
     + "FROM profiling.MiniProfilerTimings "
     + "WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM profiling.MiniProfilers "
     + "WHERE profiling.MiniProfilers.Id = MiniProfilerId "
     + "AND profiling.MiniProfilers.Started < GETDATE() - " 
     + configuration.GetSection("ProfilingData")["DaysToKeep"] + ")");
```

This join 2 tables to get the date from when the Profiler is created and deletes if the date is under DaysToKeep it seems to work fine on small tables and when it's not much data to process. It will fail every time if the amount of rows is to large. I'm not sure why this happens but i'm thinking it has to do with my transaction not being properly created and commited.

Here is the transaction method:

```
  private static void ExecuteDatabaseTransaction(IConfiguration configuration, string commandText)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["SignupDatabase"]))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.Transaction = transaction;
                        command.CommandText = commandText;
                        var rowsDeleted = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Console.WriteLine("Rows Affected: " + rowsDeleted);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Records are deleted from database.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
                    Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

                    try
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                        Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
                        throw;
                    }
                    throw;
                }
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `"DELETE profiling.MiniProfilerTimings + "FROM profiling.MiniProfilerTimings"` It would seem to me that there is a `"` missing between `profiling.MiniProfilerTimings` and the `+`

Comment: Messed up the formatting trying to make it fit, it will compile :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to a very large database requiring a lot of joins and a delete that overall takes very long time to complete.

If you add CommandTimout = 0 it will not timeout, but beware that infinite timeout is not the most optimal solution.

```
  int rowsAffected;
  connection.Open();
  var command = connection.CreateCommand();
  var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

  command.Connection = connection;
  command.CommandTimeout = 0;
  command.Transaction = transaction;
```